# 'Unknown Artist' in Music Player.

Tags: music-player, id3-tag

I have some 'unknown artist's in the Equalizer + Music Player. I know this question has been asked before but I do not know how to edit it. I have MusicTag on my laptop. Can someone please give instructions on how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The default Music Player app does not inlcude an option to edit your tags. You need to either use a Album Editor software or use an app from the playstore to edit song name, album art, track number etc. I have used [Rocket Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer&hl=en) to edit/update mp3 tag information. Using Rocket player you can edit tags like Title, Artist, Album, Genre, Disc Number, Track Number, Year and Album Art information.

For advanced operation like adding or updating lyrics, Character encoding etc look into the list available on Google PlayStore under [id3 tag editing apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=id3%20music%20tag%20editor&c=apps&hl=en) for which ever corresponds to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have used the id3 tag editor: Star Music or something like that. When I click the 'unknown artist' it opens and it shows the artists name for some reason. And I would prefer to use the Equalizer + Music Player.

Comment: After opening the unknown aritist song file, did you edit the file with apropriate tag? and by _itlaic_I would prefer to use the Equalizer + Music Player_italic_ means it is not available  in your Music Player or what?

Comment: I mean I don't know how to use the tag editor as I prefer Equalizer+ to Rocket Player but i dont know how to edit the tags. I would like to use a mac/pc app because I can edit the music for both the laptop and my phone. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK Equalizer+ Music Player's decription doesn't have tag editing feature. You can use other [id3 tag editing apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=id3%20music%20tag%20editor&c=apps&hl=en) or different music player like [Rocket Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.AnotherMusicPlayer&hl=en)/ [PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&hl=en)/ [Meridian Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.iii.romulus.meridian&hl=en) etc which includes both music player and id3 tag editing functionality in them.

Comment: Its all good. I redownloaded the songs which had the problem and its all good. Thanks for your help.